# Deploying Docker container with NGINX to a domain

Tags: docker, nginx

Having pushed to DockerHub and successfully tagged a image, I can create remotly a docker container on a Digital Ocean droplet. That's good, but since I host more than one website on this IP, I use the `NginX server`. My goal is, having `example.com` nginx config, to set up and deploy the docker container into this website (example.com) with the Engine-X.

```
docker stack deploy -c ~/etc/example.com/docker-compose.yml example.com
```

I tried to specify the path, also creating the docker based on the NGINX image, but nothing actually worked for me.

My nginx example.com config:

```
server {

        root /etc/example.com/docker-compose.yml (???);
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; (??)

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/bratac.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/bratac.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated, I really dont know what to do next, researched deep in the net..

Best Regards

Comment: After reading the question, I'm not clear what the problem is. Is something not working? Are you getting some sort of error?